# Кнопка Gradle Sync

Tags: android-studio

Почему после импорта проекта нет кнопки **Gradle sync**? Как добавить эту кнопку в тулбар?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас явно что-то сломалось. Ингода помогает перезапуск студии. Плюс, возможно, в local.properties неверно путь до AndroidSDK указан